Alter table showing errors in JDBC programs
I am trying to add two columns in an already existing table Contact_Info using MySQL.When I am doing this using MySQL command line client, its wrking perfectly. But if I try to do this in a JDBC program, writing the following code
String alter_query = "alter table Contact_Info"
                    + "add column Phone varchar(30) not null after Last_Name,"
                    + "add column Email varchar(50) not null after Phone";

its giving me error saying you have syntax error in your SQL.
I tried this query string to execute with a ';' appended and without it;but of no use
String alter_query = "alter table Contact_Info"
                    + "add column Phone varchar(30) not null after Last_Name,"
                    + "add column Email varchar(50) not null after Phone";

Can anyone tell me where I am wrong? What is mistake in my syntax?

For future reference, if you call System.out.println(alter_query); the cause of your problem should be clear.

if you check your sql, it starts as "alter table Contact_Infoadd column Phone ..."  - 1) the table most certainly is not Contact_Infoadd; and 2) column is not a valid command for alter table

If you're using Java 15 or later, you can use text blocks for multi-line strings, instead of concatenating. This would make it easier to avoid this mistake.

This Question should be not be closed. The “caused by typos” close-reason is for incidental accidental typos that ruin syntax. Here we have not a mere typo but a fundamental lack of awareness or understanding about concatenation. Every new programmer has to gain this understanding. So, this Question should be left open, as a valid issue. And it can be used to link other duplicates.

Concatenate with SPACE character
It seems like your code syntax is almost correct but I found a little issue in your code.
You didn't add a space at the end of each line and that is the reason for the syntax error, because all lines will be merged without any space, like this alter table Contact_Infoadd column. As you can see Contact_Info and add is connected without space and that is a syntax error.
To avoid the issue, please add a SPACE character as shown here:
String alter_query = "ALTER TABLE Contact_Info "  // ⬅️ Notice SPACE character at the end. 
                   + "ADD COLUMN Phone VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL AFTER Last_Name, "
                   + "ADD COLUMN Email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL AFTER Phone";

Text blocks
Alternatively, use the text blocks feature.
In a text block, each line of text remains intact. The line-terminator is preserved. No need for a SPACE at the end. Indeed, your IDE may even suggest removing any whitespace characters from the ends.
String alter_query = """
        ALTER TABLE Contact_Info
        ADD COLUMN Phone VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL AFTER Last_Name,
        ADD COLUMN Email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL AFTER Phone
        """;

For SQL, such multiline text is acceptable. Other languages being embedded may not accept multiline text, so you would instead use concatenation.

Thank you very much. My problem is solved. Great observation.

Hi, @SandipNath, You are welcome. If it helps you, you can see What should I do when someone answers my question?

Note: the text block solution is adding newline characters after each line - the string results in "ALTER TABLE Contact_Info\nADD COLUMN Phone ..." - this is no problem with SQL, but maybe for some other use case (I actually prefer the SQL statements with  newlines since easier to debug and such)

@user85421 I added your important point. Thank you.
